# Designing an Iterator to throw an exception on dereference

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, throw, hpx

I need to find a way to test my exception handling in a function I wrote called `hpx::parallel::copy`. Other functions in the library such as `hpx::parallel::transform` are easy to test as a predicate can be passed in which throws an exception, but `copy` takes no predicate.

I think my best solution would be to use an iterator that throws on dereference somehow, though I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this......any other suggestions to solving this problem are welcome as well. Here is a code example of my problem

```
//transform.cpp , testing exceptions
bool caught_exception = false;
    try {
        base_iterator outiter = hpx::parallel::transform(policy,
            iterator(boost::begin(c)), iterator(boost::end(c)), boost::begin(d),
            [](std::size_t v) {    //easy, predicate can be passed
                throw std::runtime_error("test");
                return v;
            });

        HPX_TEST(false);
    }
    //catching exceptions etc...
```

---

```
//copy.cpp, testing exceptions 
bool caught_exception = false;
    try {
        base_iterator outiter = hpx::parallel::copy(policy,
            iterator(boost::begin(c)), iterator(boost::end(c)), boost::begin(d)); //no predicate... how can I throw?
        HPX_TEST(false);
    }
    //catching exceptions etc..
```

to be more specific, I want to be able to modify what exactly I want to `throw` in order to test multiple scenarios, this just means I can't use an implementation that throws out of range or other exceptions I can't control, I need to throw specific exceptions.

Comment: You could try writing your own iterator based on `boost::iterator_facade` (not strictly necessary, but simplifies the task a lot) and throwing in the dereference function (or any other function that you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach different from constructing your own iterators would be to construct a *decorator* class of an already existing iterator class. A toy example may be:

```
#include<functional>

/**
 * @brief Decorates an iterator to permit code injection before dereferencing 
 */
template<class T>
struct IteratorDecorator : public T {

  template<class V>
  IteratorDecorator(T iterator, V f) : T(iterator) , m_callback(f) {}

  typename T::value_type & operator*() {
      m_callback();
      return T::operator*();
  }

private:
  std::function<void()> m_callback;
};

/**
 * @brief Convenience function just for type deduction 
 */
template<class T, class V>
IteratorDecorator<T> decorate(T iterator, V v) {
  return IteratorDecorator<T>(iterator,v);
}
```

This may be used in client code like this:

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> ivec {1, 3, 5, 6};

  try {
    for_each(ivec.begin(),ivec.end(),[](int& x){ cout << x << endl; } );
    for_each(decorate(ivec.begin(), [](){ cout << "decorated : "; }), 
             decorate(ivec.end()  , [](){}),
             [](int& x){ cout << x << endl; }); 
    for_each(decorate(ivec.begin(), [](){ throw runtime_error("This one throws"); }), 
             decorate(ivec.end()  , [](){}),
             [](int& x){ cout << x << endl; } );
  } catch( exception& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;   
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If you want to experiment with the code, you can find a working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61c36f82a0717aad).

Comment: Ended up taking this route, your implementation worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to construct your iterators with a back-reference to the container they iterate over. Whenever you increment the container's `end()`, or decrement its `begin()`, or when you dereference anything outside the container's range, you throw an exception. Because the iterator has a reference to the container, you have all this information. The overhead is a simple reference (or pointer) per iterator, and a small amount of logic in the `operator--`, `operator++` and `operator*`.

Microsoft use such an approach in their [**Checked Iterators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985928.aspx) which you can turn on when using their Standard Library. A sample [**implementation**](http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/safestl.zip) is given in [**SafeSTL**](http://www.horstmann.com/safestl.html). E.g. their `vector<T>` looks a bit like this:

```
template<class T>
class vector
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
         // regular iterator interface
    private:
         std::vector<T>* owner; // used by implementation to do checking
    };

    // rest of vector<T> interface
};
```

Comment: Would you know if I can find the actual source of Checked Iterators? I can't seem to find if it is open sourced or not, I'd like to see an example of how this is done.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose see my update with a link to SafeSTL

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do the simplest possible thing and write a value type whose copy assignment operator throws (and/or move assignment operator, copy and move constructors,...).

Since you populate the container in the first place, you can even select which values throw, if you want. There's a lot less boilerplate than writing an iterator.

NB. I'm assuming you want to test your algorithm by forcing an exception. I think TemplateRex's suggestion is aimed more at iterators which catch accidental misuse at runtime. Feel free to clarify.

---

### Sample implementations:

The simplest possible value type - it doesn't have any actual value, and always throws on copy or move:

```
struct TrivialThrowOnCopy {
  TrivialThrowOnCopy() = default;
  TrivialThrowOnCopy(TrivialThrowOnCopy const &) {
    throw std::runtime_error("copy");
  }
  TrivialThrowOnCopy(TrivialThrowOnCopy&&) {
    throw std::runtime_error("move");
  }
};
```

Or you could have one where you explicitly tell each instance whether to throw or not:

```
struct ConfigurableThrowOnCopy {
    bool should_throw_;
    explicit ConfigurableThrowOnCopy(bool b = false) : should_throw_(b) {}
    ConfigurableThrowOnCopy(ConfigurableThrowOnCopy const &other) 
    : should_throw_(other.should_throw_) {
        if (should_throw_) throw std::runtime_error("copy");
    }
    ConfigurableThrowOnCopy(ConfigurableThrowOnCopy &&other) 
    : should_throw_(other.should_throw_) {
        if (should_throw_) throw std::runtime_error("move");
    }
};
```

or one where every _n_th copy throws:

```
struct CountingThrowOnCopy {
    static unsigned counter;
    // set CountingThrowOnCopy::counter = 5 to make the 5th copy throw
    CountingThrowOnCopy() = default;
    CountingThrowOnCopy(ConfigurableThrowOnCopy const &) {
        if (!--counter) throw std::runtime_error("copy");
    }
    CountingThrowOnCopy(ConfigurableThrowOnCopy&&) {
        if (!--counter) throw std::runtime_error("move");
    }
};
```

or any of the above but wrapping an actual value:

```
template <typename T>
struct ConfigurableThrowOnCopyT {
    T value_;
    bool should_throw_;
    explicit ConfigurableThrowOnCopyT(T const &t, bool b = false)
    : value_(t), should_throw_(b) {}
    ConfigurableThrowOnCopyT(ConfigurableThrowOnCopyT const &other)
    : value_(other.value_), should_throw_(other.should_throw_) {
        if (should_throw_) throw std::runtime_error("copy");
    }
    ConfigurableThrowOnCopyT(ConfigurableThrowOnCopyT &&other)
   : value(std::move(other.value_)), should_throw_(other.should_throw_) {
        if (should_throw_) throw std::runtime_error("move");
    }
    T& operator() { return value_; }
    T const& operator() const { return value_; }
};
```

Comment: You're spot on, could you go into a little more detail about writing a value type? maybe a super short example or pseudo code if possible?